# Display multiple values of a key

Tags: groovy, keyvaluepair

I have a key and  multiple value pairs.how to display the values.

```
def empData=[[dob:01/10/1970, qualifications:[java:[5/6, 7]],name:'T1'],
             [dob:01/02/1981,qualification:[DBA:['Professional','Specialist']],name:'T2']]

empData.eachWithIndex{item,idx->
    println("emp dob:"+item.dob);
    String[] qualifications = item.qualifications.get("java");
    println("qualification is:"+qualifications[0]);
    println("qualification is:"+qualifications[1]);
    println("emp name is:"+name);
}
```

I want the output to be as below:

```
// first record
   01/10/1970
   5/6
   7
   T1

   second record
   01/02/1981
   Professional
   Specialist
   T2


  Throws an error null pointer exception.
```

Comment: You use another `each` in your code (same as you do with the outer loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answers, there are issues with your code which seem to indicate that it would be useful for you to spend a little more time with the groovy documentation. With that being said, it is sometimes useful with a working example.

The below code:

```
def employees=[[dob:            '01/10/1970', 
                name:           'T1',
                qualifications: [java:   ['5 years', '15 projects'],
                                 python: ['Senior Developer']]],
               [dob:            '01/02/1981', 
                name:           'T2',
                qualifications: [dba:  ['Professional','Specialist']]]]

employees.indexed().each { idx, employee ->
  println "       Employee: ${employee.name}"
  println "            dob: ${employee.dob}"

  employee.qualifications.each { field, qualifications -> 
    println "                 ${field} - ${qualifications.join(', ')}"
  }
}
```

prints out:

```
       Employee: T1
            dob: 01/10/1970
                 java - 5 years, 15 projects
                 python - Senior Developer
       Employee: T2
            dob: 01/02/1981
                 dba - Professional, Specialist
```

when run. The formatting is not exactly what you specified, but at least you can get a feel  for how nested iteration can be done. The data in your example is broken to a point where it is hard to know exactly what you intended. I formatted the data in a way I assume is in line with your intent.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code. First, to solve the `NullPointerException`, you simply forgot to state the receiver of the `name` property:

```
println("emp name is:" + item.name) // Property `name` is set on `item`
```

Furthermore, the Maps contain different keys. The first one has a `qualifications` key, the latter a `qualification` - notice the missing letter s? And lastly, upon equalizing the keys, there should occur another `NullPointerException`, because you are trying to get the first and the second entry of the *java* qualification, which doesn't exist for the second empData entry.

After solving those issues, it should be a no-brainer to get the desired output by changing the values types to String. Your values are statements there, i.e. 01/10/1970 is a division which yields `0.0000507614`, the same applies to the `5/6` statement.

I would suggest reading the [Groovy Documentation: Operators](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html) and maybe, first, the [Groovy Documentation: Syntax](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) pages, which are really well written and deep dive into the language basics with simple yet great examples.